# Select uploaded files by key

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an ASP.NET application I want to process uploaded files. The `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys` contains the following:

```
[0]File2    
[1]File2    
[2]flTeklif    
[3]flTeklif    
[4]flTeklif    
[5]flTeklif
```

How can I select only the uploaded files that have key `flTeklif` into a `List<HttpPostedFile>`?

I tried this:

```
var uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys
                         .Where(s=>s.stringname == "flTeklif")
```

But that only selects the keys, not the files. How can I select the `Files.Where(key == "flTeklif")`?

Comment: What is your problem? U have already write an answer to this

Comment: is this joke i can not solve this problem for 2 hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`HttpRequest.Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx) is an [`HttpFileCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection(v=vs.110).aspx), whose [`AllKeys` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpfilecollection.allkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) is a string array.

So you can just use `AllKeys.Where(s => s == "flTeklif")`.

So far for the literal interpretation of your question, which is probably why you're pretty heavily down- and closevoted as it doesn't really make any sense.

If your actual question is *"How can I select the files that have `flTeklif` as their key"*, use:

```
var files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
var result = new List<HttpPostedFile>();

for (int i = 0; i < files.AllKeys.Count; i++)
{
    if (files.AllKeys[i] == "flTeklif")
    {
        result.Add(files.AllKeys[i]);
    }
}
```

Then `result` will contain the files you're interested in.

Comment: how can i set filtered list to HttpFileCollection  ?

Answer (score 2):

OK i understand. may be

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Cast<HttpPostedFile>().Where(c => c.FileName.Contains("flTeklif")).ToList();
```

Comment: how can i set filtered list to HttpFileCollection  ?

Comment: No, the `Filename` will not contain the key. The key is the name the element had in the form that was posted, the filename is the name of the uploaded file.

Comment: Yes right, I have misunderstood. I will update again

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpFileCollection.GetKey(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpfilecollection.getkey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpFileCollection_GetKey_System_Int32_) method. There is no mention that `AllKeys` array order is the similiar to the files `HttpFileCollection`.

```
 int i;
 HttpFileCollection MyFileColl = Request.Files;

 for( i= 0; i< MyFileColl.Count; i++)
 {
    if( MyFileColl.GetKey(i) == "flTeklif")
    {
       //...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get a list of all uploaded files against a particular key

```
HttpFileCollection files = null;
try { files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files; } catch { }
var allUploadedFilesAgainstThisKey = files.GetMultiple(singleKey);      // singleKey is a string
        // allUploadedFilesAgainstThisKey is of type IList<HttpPostedFile>
```