# Receive files from multiple form data keys in ASP.NET MVC Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am working on **Web APIs** in an **ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework)** web application.
The **.NET Framework version is 4.7.2**

I have a web API (HTTP **Post method**) for file upload, where I am using the following code to retrieve the files

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
var files = context.Request.Files;
// returns List<HttpPostedFile>
```

**The user can upload multiple files**. The above line returns a list of file objects, and I am fine so far.

When I am calling the API from Postman, I prepare the payload like shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Note: in Postman, it is possible to add files in the POST API request payload (see how [in here](https://medium.com/apis-with-valentine/automatically-testing-file-uploads-multipart-form-data-with-postman-and-gitlab-ci-ebfa371992b1)), and I am using that feature to test my API.

**Imp note**: note that in Postman, I am not providing any key for the form data.

================ ==================== ================== =====================

**=== MY ACTUAL PROBLEM ===**

Now the parties who consume my API have given a new requirement. They want to upload files using multiple keys, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have to process the files for each key differently. Therefore, **I cannot use** my previous code

```
var files = context.Request.Files;
```

because this code returns all files together, I cannot determine which file belongs to which key.

**Is it possible to retrieve the files using the key?**

Answer (score 0):

References: CodeCaster's answer in [Select uploaded files by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962140/select-uploaded-files-by-key)

I do not know of any method that can retrieve files by key. Inside the list returned by

```
var files = context.Request.Files;
```

the individual files can be accessed by numeric index, but not by key.
Therefore files["keyName"] returns null.

However, there is a roundabout way to determine which files belongs to which key. The code is below:

```
                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                var files = context.Request.Files;
                var allKeys = files.AllKeys;
                Dictionary<string, List<HttpPostedFile>> allFilesByKeys = new Dictionary<string, List<HttpPostedFile>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    string keyForThisFile = files.GetKey(i);
                    if (allFilesByKeys.ContainsKey(keyForThisFile))
                    {
                        allFilesByKeys[keyForThisFile].Add(files[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        allFilesByKeys[keyForThisFile] = new List<HttpPostedFile>();
                        allFilesByKeys[keyForThisFile].Add(files[i]);
                    }
                }
```